# how can i use pixel position 'x'(Halide::Var) value as a limit of a for loop?

Tags: c++, halide

I am new in Halide.

I am trying to do some calculation where pixel position 'x' should be set as the limit of the for loop. For that, I wrote the following code but it seems i can not use halide variable as a limit of a for loop.

Is there a solution for that?

My code:

```
Halide::Var x, y;

Halide::Expr L;

Halide::Func mat,A;

L = 0;

for (int k=1; k<=x-1; k++)

        L +=  mat(k,y) * mat(k,x);

mat(x,y) = Halide::select(x==y, (A(x, y) - L),

                              y>x, (A(x,y) - L)/mat(x,x),

                              0);
```

it gives the error message:

> "error: could not convert ‘Halide::operator<=(int, Halide::Expr)
>   Halide::operator-(Halide::Expr, int)(1))’ from ‘Halide::Expr’ to
>   ‘bool’      for (int k=1; k<=x-1; k++)"

Comment: Seems `Halide` lacks some overloads. Ask them. In the while, try with `Var k` instead of `int k`.

Comment: Hi, in a normal for loop it is not possible to use Halide::Var. need conversion from Halide::Var. Is there any Halide for loop?

Comment: "in a for loop" Why not? I know nothing about `Halide`, but I guess they have something to do "Var aritmethic". If not, again, ask Halide team.

Comment: How to ask Halide team?

Comment: In their [web](https://halide-lang.org/) there are some links. I suggest the `gitter`.

Answer (score 1):

`Halide::Expr` and `Halide::Var` don't have explicit values at C++ compilation time; they are placeholders for values that are expressed in the resulting Halide code. Thus, you can't use them in a C++ `for` loop. The equivalent in Halide is to use an `RDom` to specify an explicit range, e.g.,

```
    Halide::RDom k(1, x-1);  // RDom is [min, extent], not [min, max]
    Halide::Expr L;
    L = 0;
    L += mat(k,y) * mat(k,x);
```

or, more simply,

```
    Halide::RDom k(1, x-1);  // RDom is [min, extent], not [min, max]
    Halide::Expr L = Halide::sum(mat(k,y) * mat(k,x));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven Johnson! I will try with your suggestion. :-)

Comment: I don't think you can use Vars in the bounds of an RDom. You probably want to put a plausible upper bound, then use RDom::where to trim it down to the range you actually want: RDom r(k, 1, 1024); r.where(r < x);

Comment: Yup, you are right Andrew Adams! I can't use a Var as the bounds of an RDom. I need to give specific values as bound of an RDom. So, I need to find another solution for it.

Comment: Thank you Steven Johnson and Andrew Adams! it works fine with RDom::where. But there is another problem should I write a new Question? As in my Question, some later mat(x,y) needs the previous value of mat(x,y). i.e. It is a recursive function. But it gives an error:   "Can't call Func "mat" because it has not yet been defined.
The program has unexpectedly finished." ------what to do now?